# How to modify alternate links during SSR using nuxt and Vue i18n

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

I want to modify the href attribute(to remove query string) for specific pages
like screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

or maybe entirely remove the link element for specific pages

How can I archive that?

Answer (score 0):

With nuxt, you just have to specify a `head` function that defines these links:

```js
export default {
  head() {
    return {
      link: [
        { rel: 'alternate', hreflang: 'zh', href: 'http://my-main-alternate-link' },
        { rel: 'alternate', hreflang: 'en', href: 'http://my-english-alternate-link' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You'll have to manually specify all the links for all languages I'm afraid.

Comment: thanks for replying, and how to exactly disable the default links in head?

Comment: I don't think you can. I'll take a look to the source code just in case but I don't know that option :/